# badge notification is not showing if laptop is connected to external monitor

Tags: c#, uwp, badge

I have a uwp app that shows a badge icon whenever a new message is received. Recently when I connected my laptop to an external monitor it suddenly stopped showing a badge icon. Is there any system setting that can affect the notification toaster or taskbar badge?

Comment: Any code will better help understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 10 **Focus Assist** can affect your notifications. Toast notifications won't be showed if you are in "Priority only"/"Alarms only" mode. If you connect an external display to your PC, Windows may assume you are presenting and enable Focus Assist.

To make sure Focus Assist is disabled, you can either go to action center or to `Settings -> System -> Focus Assist`.

You can also check if your app is allowed to send notifications by going to `Settings -> System -> Notifications & actions -> Get notifications from these senders...`

Comment: I have checked all settings are enabled. Notifications are directly going into action center but not showing any toaster